# How to find a good photo gallery for my website?

Tags: php, javascript, cms, photo-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

For my website I'm searching for a really simple gallery module that looks like the one use by Dropbox. But I'd like to have 2 additional features: allow visitors to make comments and display the number of hits of a photo.

I was googling a lot for such gallerys, but could find anyone that really matched my requirements. Could someone reocommend a simple good-looking gallery that fullfills these requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Zenphoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/)? It's a nice gallery system for displaying photos. It runs on PHP and MySQL, and is extensible and themable.

Answer (score 1):

[Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net) is updated quite often, and this [BitNami installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/coppermine) makes it really easy to setup this gallery. It has the two features you are asking for :)  (and much more)

Another one having that functionality is [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com).