# Design Techniques to represent a series of photos in a website

Tags: website-design, thumbnail

An important part of our site will be the photo part in which we'll have artistic photos (no snapshots, no stock).

We'll have different areas there like 'Recent additions', 'Popular' etc. For these areas, besides the classical plain-vanilla thumbnail row, can someone give other techniques for represent these series of images?

We're looking for something distinctive, outstanding and intuitive as well. Don't forget that the photos are mainly artistic.

TIA for your responses.

Comment: Would a JQuery image gallery/slider/album be an option?

Comment: @Goboozo: Well, yes and no. We aren't against jQuery, Flash and/or any other **technology**. We hunt now **ideas**. Perhaps a response with a link to a neat implementation of jQuery which will fit to art photos will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a related question to these matters [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/how-to-find-a-good-photo-gallery-for-my-website/7362). I hope it helps somehow.